# Leverage permalinks with AJAX

Tags: permalinks, ajax

I'm trying to implement some AJAX to my theme, but there are a few things I cannot get my head (or Google) around.

I have a custom post type named "Faculty" and a page displaying the featured image for each entry in the custom post type in a grid that links to /faculty/entry1, /faculty/entry2 etc.

Instead of loading a new page with the content I'm trying to load the content above the grid using the admin-ajax.php file.

But how can I implement this leveraging the current "pretty" permalinks?

What I would like to achieve is that the user clicks the featured image and the url will change to /faculty/item2 and I will receive the content for item2 via AJAX. And if the user manually enters /faculty/item2 in the browser the same faculty page will load with the content from item2.

I really hope the explanation makes sense - and that somebody can give me a pointer in the right direction.

EDIT: This is an example of the functionality I'm looking for, just with the WordPress permalinks implemented: http://themewich.com/aware/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [html5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) with which you can change the URL at the address bar whenever you want. Works on anything modern which is not IE, but maybe [this utility](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) will help with IE.